# node.js socket.io connection timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to connect to my node.js + socket.io chat server through the use of telnet for checking and I'm getting

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

and below is the benchmark of the server in browser inspector.

[Browser inspector benchmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipndt.png)

The code(server and client side) already pass the testing, however when I migrated the server in my production server, this problem appears occasionally.

Is anyone there already experience this kind of bug or issue please help.

What I'm checking right now is the server specifications and the internet connectivity. What are the possible problems with regards with this two matter.

Comment: We cannot do system integration testing by blog.  We cannot fix intermittent network bugs by blog.

Comment: @MartinJames what do you need?

Comment: This is already fixed. The issue is the port that I'm using, the firewall is blocking the port.